# Is disk witness still the recommended best option for 2 node cluster (versus file share) in SQL server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-2019

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/cc770830(v=ws.10)#local-two-node-cluster

It says that the disk witness is the recommended best option.

Assuming an FCI solution is planned on a SAN, is disk witness still the recommended best option for 2 node cluster (versus file share) in SQL server 2019?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For classic failover clusters a disk witness is easier to manage than a file share. Consider the [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/manage-cluster-quorum) for different witness types.

A fileshare needs another a server to host it, so that's one more server to the enviroment and extra dependency. For extra HA, the share needs to be a clustered SMB file share, which increases complexity. Also, the share needs permissions setup to allow cluster nodes to access it, whilst Windows Clustering does all the work for a quorum disk.